# Cannot get this jQuery AJAX + JSONP to work. "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I hope someone can help me with this.

Every time I try to run the code below, I get the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is the client JS code:

```
function checkIP() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "http://www.acme.ie/test/checkip.php",
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback',
        success: function(data) {
                alert("success");
        },
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {},
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
    })
}

jQuery.noConflict();
checkIP();
```

This is the server response code (http://www.acme.ie/test/checkip.php):

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo "jsonCallback({'1' : '1'})";
```

I've looked at many examples and I appear to be doing everything correctly.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There's plenty wrong here (async is incompatible with JSONP, hard coding the callback function name leads to race conditions, and the content-type for JSONP is `application/javascript`), but [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/9mgcnop8/).

Comment: async is set to false, all the tutorials say it should be application/json, and all the tutorials hard code the function name...

Comment: But that's super interesting it is working for you! Perhaps there is something wrong with my jQuery version.

Comment: You are looking at wrong tutorials. `application/json` is the correct content-type for JSON. JSONP is not JSON, it is JavaScript. I've never seen a JSONP tutorial that hardcoded the callback name, they almost all get it from `$_GET['callback']`.

Comment: Figured it out, my browser was loading a cached version. I had to clear my cache. Problem: adding $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); isn't stopping it from being cached. I've also added the various no-cache meta tags to the calling HTML page. Do you have any idea how I can stop this from caching?

Comment: Figured out the caching problem. If I send unique data each time with the request, it is not cached. Thanks for your help Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
```